# Open new workbook after enter "TAK" value in any row of the specified column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to open a workbook in a specific location when sb enter the word "TAK" in column C (starting from C2).

Ultimately, many people will be adding values there, so there will be more and more of these rows in column C. Each time a user types "TAK", I would like a specific workbook to open.

At the moment my code looks like this and does not work - can you help?

```
    Sub add_ticket()
    
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range 
Set SrchRng = Range("C:C")
    
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If cel.Value = "TAK" Then
            Workbooks.Open "HERE IS THE LOCALIZATION OF FILE TO OPEN"
        End If Next cel
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Please tell us what is wrong. Also you might want to have a look into the `Worksheet_Change()` event. So the code runs automatically when you change values.

Comment: `End If` and `Next cel` should be wo separate lines.

Comment: In this case - does not work mean exactly this. Nothing happens. I use the code for the worksheet, not as module. So, after enter "YES" value in column C (many rows checked) nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

*A Quick Example is*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$C2:$C999")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = Trim("TAK") Then
            Debug.Print Target.Address & " Opening Workbook" ' Immediate window
            Application.Workbooks.Open ("D:\Temp\test.xlsx")
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Trim` in `Trim("TAK")`  is pretty useless isn't it? Also limiting it to 999 rows doesn't bring any benefit in my eyes. Also this line `Target.Value = Trim("TAK")` will prevent copy/paste of multiple cells (ranges) in the entire sheet. Everytime you try that and column C is involved it will throw an exception because then `Target.Value` is not a single value but an array of a value that you cannot compare to a string!